# How to split the csv file with line numbers which pass as parameter and save into different files

Tags: python

```
python script.py 2
```

Here each file will be having 2 lines. filename is having time, data,hour, second

- I have 5 line in a csv file
- I will take input from user as parameter
- if user is giving 2 then my each file will be having 2 lines each.
- first 2 line will be in first file, second two line in second file and last line is in third file
- Last file will be having one line
- Filename will be having hour minute second

below is the csv file

```
1,Network activity,ip-dst,80.179.42.44,,1,20160929
2,Payload delivery,md5,4ad2924ced722ab65ff978f83a40448e,,1,20160929
3,Network activity,domain,alkamaihd.net,,1,20160929
4,Payload delivery,md5,197c018922237828683783654d3c632a,,1,20160929
5,Network activity,domain,dnsrecordsolver.tk,,1,20160929
```

I need to divide in to 3 different files, split number of lines has to taken as argument

Below is the approach

- take the division line as parameter and save with data with time stamp

Below is the code for saving the data with date.hour,time. I need some logic to divide the line and continue from there

```
    import csv
    import time
    import sys
    
    sourceData = "Oil.csv"
    def GetLineCount():
        with open(sourceData) as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return i
    
    def MakeLog(startLine, numLines):
        destData = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.log")
        with open(sourceData, 'r') as csvfile:
            with open(destData, 'w') as dstfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                writer = csv.writer(dstfile)
                next (reader) #skip header
```

python script.py 2

then 3 files will be generate with 2 lines in each file and last file will be having one

Expected out

3 text file will be generate 2 lines each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's how you would do it in `Python3`.

```
import argparse
import time
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(n, iterable, fill_value=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fill_value, *args)


def splitter(n_lines, file):
    with open(file) as f:
        for i, payload in enumerate(grouper(n_lines, f, fill_value=''), 1):
            f_name = f"{time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}_{i*n_lines}.log"
            with open(f_name, 'w') as out:
                out.writelines(payload)


def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="File splitter")
    parser.add_argument("file", metavar="FILE", type=str, help="Target file to be chopped up")
    parser.add_argument("n_lines", type=int, default=2, help="Number of lines to output per file")
    return parser


def command_line_runner():
    parser = get_parser()
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    splitter(args['n_lines'], args['file'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_line_runner()
```

Sample run: `python3 main.py sample.csv 2` produces `3` files:

```
20200921-095943_2.log
20200921-095943_4.log
20200921-095943_6.log
```

The first two have two lines each and the last one, well, one line.

The contents of `sample.csv` is as in your example:

```
1,Network activity,ip-dst,80.179.42.44,,1,20160929
2,Payload delivery,md5,4ad2924ced722ab65ff978f83a40448e,,1,20160929
3,Network activity,domain,alkamaihd.net,,1,20160929
4,Payload delivery,md5,197c018922237828683783654d3c632a,,1,20160929
5,Network activity,domain,dnsrecordsolver.tk,,1,20160929
```

Comment: what is zip longest

Comment: @Nons `zip_longest` creates an iterator and if the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Read more here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Answer (score 2):

There is a linux [split](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) command

```
split -l 2 Oil.csv
```

would split into files of 2 lines each.

For appending hour, minute, and second to filenames,

```
split -l 2 Oil.csv --additional-suffix=`date +"%H:%M:%S"`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the line numbers to split at n lines with `(linenumber+1) % n`:

```
import sys
import datetime

def save_file(newcontent):
    savenewfile = str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".log"
    with open(savenewfile, 'w') as dstfile:
        dstfile.write(newcontent)

split_at = int(sys.argv[1])
newcontent = ""

with open("Oil.csv", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        newcontent += line
        if (i+1) % split_at == 0: # i+1 because i starts at 0
            save_file(newcontent)
            newcontent = ""

# save remaining lines
if newcontent:
    save_file(newcontent)
```

`save_file(newcontent)` will be your function to save a string to a new file.
Your timestring `%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` won't make a unique file name. You can add a counter or use `str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".log"` instead.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: i tried above code adding one function save_file(newcontent), but its not saving

Comment: @Nons Sorry, my advice about datetime was a bit unclear. The filename must be a string. For example: `str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".log"`

Comment: i tried that also save_file(newcontent)
NameError: name 'save_file' is not defined

Comment: i want to try your answer also since its very easy to understand

Comment: @Nons edited my answer. It is now complete code you can run.

Comment: no sir its still throwing error OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '2020-09-22 14:30:20.380233.log'

Comment: It works for me. Probably your operating system doesn't allow some of the used characters in filenames. it might be the `:`. `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S_%f") + ".log"` creates a more compatible name